# Angular 5: child routes are not working when I have 2 router outlet in app

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-routing, angular-router, router-outlet

I have create routes on my module and import it as child.

in an module.Routing.ts

```
export  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path : 'admin',
    component : IndexComponent,
    children :[
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent, outlet:'AdminRO' },
        { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, outlet: 'AdminRO' }
    ]
  }
];

export  const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

IN app.routing.ts

I have this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/admin', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: AppLoginComponent }
];
export  const AppRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

now when its redirecting to the first homecomponent successfully. but when i try url localhost/admin/products.

its giving me an error

```
 Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin/products'
```

Comment: try to navigate like this, http://.../admin(AdminRO:products)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove AdminRO from the router outlet which you are using in the secondary module.

Answer (score 0):

Named outlets are the targets of secondary routes. If you want to navigate to secondary routes from browser, please enter the url as follows

```
http://.../admin(AdminRO:products)
```

The admin is the primary navigation.
Parentheses surround the secondary route.
The secondary route consists of an outlet name (AdminRO), a colon separator, and the secondary route path (products).

Comment: I have tried the same url as well but still can't have success.

Comment: I have main router-outlet in app.component and the other router-outlet name "adminRO" in module main.component.